# Most efficient way to search a pixel on screen?

Tags: search, matrix, pixel

GetPixel in windows api seems to work fine, but it just takes ridiculously large amount of time (several minutes) for a screen of resolution as large as 1920x1080. I am suspecting that it is the GetPixel function, which probably takes several centiseconds to process, is lagging the whole thing behind. I was wondering if directly accessing the memory map could solve this problem? Or is there a better approximation method? What i'm hoping to achieve is searching less than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a screen shot of the current screen, and search with the bitmap you receive. That way, you'll be accessing your own memory, and it'll be much faster than calling `GetPixel()` 2073600 times.